# Return SQL Identity to VB Variable on INSERT

Tags: sql, asp-classic, ado

Hi I have some code below and I wish to return the resultant Identity Number when I execute the SQL Statement.

```
set objCnn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")

CurrMachine = "my-test-box"

ObjCnn.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Test;password=Test123;Language=British;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Source=" & CurrMachine)

strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.xyz" & _ " (field) " & _ " VALUES  (" & date & ")" & _ " SELECT @@Identity "

objCnn.Execute strSQL
```

I have added SELECT @@Identity which will return the unique ID number when I do this in SQL. If I response.write strSQL I get the SQL String rather than the resultant text.

Cheers!

### EDIT

For you Richard

```
    set objCnn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")

    CurrMachine = "my-test-srv"

    ObjCnn.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Test;password=Test123;Language=British;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=" & CurrMachine)

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO xyz" & _
                " ([date])" & _
                 " VALUES  ( " & date & " )" & _
                 " SET NOCOUNT OFF; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() ID; "

    Set rs = objCnn.Execute(strSQL)
    response.write rs("ID")
```

Comment: @gbn Not the right duplicate link. [tag:asp-classic] != [tag:c#.net]

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: it is close enough

Comment: @gbn Your answer deals with the generation of the identity value. The crux of the answer to this question is that strSQL is programmatic, asp-classic - that strSQL does not mutate after calling `.Execute`.

Answer (score 6):

ADODB.Connection.Execute runs a SQL statement, but does *not* modify the string, so of course when you inspect (or `response.write`) strSQL, it is unchanged - still contains the SQL command text.

You can capture the recordset created in the SELECT statement into a ADODB.recordset.

```
strSQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO dbo.xyz" & _
                 " (field) " & _
                 " VALUES  (" & date & ");" & _
                 " SET NOCOUNT OFF; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() ID; "
Dim rs
Set rs = objCnn.Execute(strSQL)
response.write rs("ID")
```

Note that you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY` with very very few exceptions (if one even exists).

Comment: That is the response.write rs("ID") section of the code that is failing, the INSERT Statement still works.

Comment: Same error: ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1' 

Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal. 

/myAPI/TestHarness.asp, line 87

Comment: Hi Richard have done so above, Cheers

Comment: Ahh that'll be the one, sorry missed that :) Result!